# VIM like blank lines (after the last line) in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm, ideavim

I am faced with the problem... I'm using ideavimrc where I have have set

```
set scrolloff=30
```

Is it possible to set in IDEA VIM like blank lines after the last line so that my text will be ~ at the center even when the cursor is at the end of the line. See the picture...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try checkbox in `Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Show virtual space at file bottom`.

Comment: Ah miss this option :)... map j jzz, map k kzz